# Wordpress: Previous / Next Thumbnails are showing the current thumbnail on custom post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

I have created a template that displays thumbnails with the previous and next links. This works perfectly for normal posts.

**PROBLEM**

I have used the same code for a custom post. Instead of showing the next and previous thumbnails, it shows the thumbnail for the current custom post. I have attached a screenshot to give you an idea of what I am trying to create.

[image]

**QUESTION**

Can someone figure out why this code doesn't work in a custom post? Why it is pulling through the wrong thumbnail.

Thank you so much,
Erlen

**CODE USED**

```
    <!-- Left Arrow -->
    <div class="post-pagination-left">
    <?php $prev_post = get_previous_post(); if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" class="link">

    <svg/></svg>  
    <span style="font-size:20px; font-weight:600;">&nbsp;Previous</span><br>
    <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="pagination-left-image"><?php $previousPost = get_previous_post(true); $previousthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($previousPost->ID, array(500,500) ); echo $previousthumbnail; ?></span>
    </div>


    <!-- Right Arrow -->
    <div class="post-pagination-right">
    <?php $next_post = get_next_post(); if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>" class="link">
        <span style="font-size:20px; font-weight:600;">Next&nbsp;</span>
     <svg/></svg><br> 
     <?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>

    </a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="pagination-right-image"><?php $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(300,300) ); echo $nextthumbnail; ?></span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `get_previous_post` twice but in different ways. In the second version you're setting the `$in_same_term` argument to true. My guess would be it's not finding a post so returns an empty string. `get_the_post_thumbnail()` will then get the thumbnail for the current post.

Please try the following:

```
<!-- Left Arrow -->
<div class="post-pagination-left">
    <?php // Get previous post.
    $prev_post = get_previous_post(); 

    if ( ! empty( $prev_post ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" class="link">
            <svg/></svg>  
            <span style="font-size:20px; font-weight:600;">&nbsp;Previous</span><br>
            <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?>
        </a>

        <span class="pagination-left-image">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $prev_post->ID, array( 500, 500 ) );?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Be sure to repeat this for the next post as well.

You may want to move the conditional outside of the div. I haven't done this in my answer in case it breaks your layout. There are other improvements you could make sure as passing `get_permalink` an object instead of a post ID, clearing up inline CSS, etc.